# calling a function on complete of multiple ajax events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So say i have multiple ajax requests that are fired at the same time through a parent function. Each ajax function has a seperate individual completion function which are unrelated to each other. If i want a further function to execute upon completion of all ajax functions, but after the completion functions specified in each individual ajax function, how would i go about this?

```
function ajax1(str) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        data: "q=" + str,
        url: 'foo.php',
        success: function (result) {
            //success!
        }

    },
    complete: function (data) {

        function ajaxcomplete1();
    },

    )
};

function ajax2(str) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        data: "q=" + str,
        url: 'foo.php',
        success: function (result) {
            //success!
        }

    },
    complete: function (data) {

        function ajaxcomplete2();
    },

    )
};

function ajaxcall() {
    ajax1();
    ajax2();
}

function allajaxcomplete() {
    // some code to be executed on completion of all ajax requests but after individual "ajaxcomplete1" and "ajaxcomplete2" functions
}
ajaxcall();
allajaxcomplete();
```

Comment: Read about **callback functions in javascript**

Comment: @RayonDabre I have, however couldn't find the answer.. hence me using stackoverflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.ajax` returns a [jQuery Deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (a promise). You then just have to use [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to call a function when all those promises are resolved:

```
function ajax1(str) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        data: "q=" + str,
        url: 'foo.php',
        success: function (result) {
            //success!
            ajaxcomplete1();
        }
    });
};

function ajax2(str) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        data: "q=" + str,
        url: 'foo.php',
        success: function (result) {
            //success!
            ajaxcomplete2();
        }
    });
};

function ajaxcall() {
    // store the promises (for clarity, you also could call the functions directly in the when)
    var d1 = ajax1(),
        d2 = ajax2();

    // this function will be called only when both promises d1 and d2 are resolved
    $.when(d1, d2).done(function(result1, result2){
        // do stuff when both functions are done
        // result1 and result2 are the result of the ajax calls inside your functions

        allajaxcomplete();
    });
}
```

Comment: if i not mistaken, `$.ajax` already return promisse, so not need in manual created deferred object

Comment: @Grundy Fixed. Thanks